# "Zoom out the map"? "Zoom the map out"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

On a website, I show a Google Map with markers. I have some text that says

> If you can't see them all, zoom the map out to reveal the rest.

This sounds kind of lame, I also considered:

> If you can't see them all, zoom out the map to reveal the rest.

But that sounds even worse. Can anyone offer a more pleasing alternative?

Comment: BTW, happy 30K on SO!

Comment: The usage is: to zoom in and zoom out on an image. So, you can zoom in or out on the map, which is an image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem in both your examples is that *zoom in/out* isn't transitive and therefore shouldn't be used with a direct object.  I'd say:

> If you can't see all the markers on the map, zoom out.

You don't really need to say "to reveal the rest" because it's implied by the [protasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protasis_%28linguistics%29) (*if you can't see them*) that the [apodosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apodosis) (*zoom out*) is the solution to the problem.

Comment: I edited my post to include the exact text in question (rather than my ealier rough memory). Would you mind suggesting a replacement for the update. Thanks for your help

Comment: Already done.  I saw your update.